# Can I pass host headers in the collectd write_http plugin?

Tags: collectd

Nothing in the documentation or manpages for the collectd plugin 'write_http' seems to provide any sort of mechanism for passing HTTP host header information. I am trying to pipe data out to an API that accepts a security token in the header and see no reasonable way of doing that with the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's a `Header` option - we can safely disregard this question now.

> **Header** ***Header***
>
> A HTTP header to add to the request. Multiple headers are added if this option is specified more than once.
>
> Example:
>
> `Header "X-Custom-Header: custom_value"`

*From https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_write_http*